# Why did ajax break when sub forms are loaded in a c:forEach block?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I found a strange behavior using JSF 2.0 and Ajax functionality. Ajax seems to no longer work if a subpage is loaded in c:forEach block.

I am using a main form which includes a set of subpages dynamically (based on a backend configuration):

```
<c:forEach items="#{workflowController.editorSections}" var="section">
    <div class="imixs-portlet" >
        <ui:include src="/pages/workitems/parts/#{section.url}.xhtml"/>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

In this case it is not possible to use simple f:ajax render"..." tags.

For example the following code snippet will only work for the first subpage be included in the c:forEach tag :

```
<h:commandButton value="Welcome Me">
        <f:ajax execute="name" render="output" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:outputText id="output" value="#{childWorkitemController.name}" />
```

If I try to use f:ajax in the subpage which was included after the first subpage, then in this subpage ajax will no longer work.

So for now my only working solution was to skip the c:forEach block and include all subpages manually.

Why did ajax behavior breaks when subpages are included in a c:forEach block?

Comment: The term "subform" sounds scary. Are you nesting forms? This is invalid in HTML and inherently thus also in JSF.

Comment: I renamed 'subform' into 'subpage'. I have only one h:form element.

Comment: I figured out, that when I add an action atribute to the h:commandButton pointing to the main page, ajax works again.

Comment: As I thought before, it's not a good idea a add an action event. Things become more and more strange. I fact the problem is the c:forEach block including subpages dynamically. When I include them hard coded without a c:forEach, ajax works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that I did not use a ui:composition tag for my subpages.

This was the structure of my subpage before

```
<f:subview xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" id="mysubpage">

<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="imixs-form-section"
        id="minutes_body" binding="#{minutesBody}">
....

</f:subview>
```

After I changed into a ui:composition everything is working!

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="imixs-form-section"
        id="minutes_body" binding="#{minutesBody}">
....

</ui:composition>
```

With thie ui:composition tag my subpages can be included in any situation and ajax is working as expected.
Only in one situation it was still necessary to surround a part of a subpage with a f:subview element.
Otherwise I got a alert box with the message:

malformedXML: During update: workitem_form:form_panel:j_idt179 not found

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

<!-- subview tag necessary here -->
<f:subview>

    <!-- minutes body -->
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="imixs-form-section"
        id="minutes_body" binding="#{minutesBody}">
.....
    </f:subview>
 </ui:composition>
```